# Pattern for error notifications in MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Is there any pattern for cross-platform error handling in MvvmCross, mainly Android and iOS?
For example:

1. In the model a call is made to a webservice. The call fails e.g. due to network not available.
2. Imagine a text input field that my application checks. When it contains abc, everything is fine. Otherwise an error message shall be shown.

How to propagate the error messages for these cases to the view? How to process the error message in the view?

Can someone provide some best practice samples?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft AppCenter Crashes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/xamarin) has native and Xamarin modules for iOS and Android which will allow you to report and view handled and unhandled exceptions.

[Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) can be used to handle automatic retry of web requests.

MvvmCross has a [logging system](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/logging) that can be connected to NLog, Serilog, etc. to log errors/information to a log file on the device. You can attach the log file to AppCenter Error Report (although it is currently limited to 7MB file attachments)

[FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) can be used to validate objects. You could handle the validation in the ViewModel then use a [MvvmCross Interaction](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/advanced/mvxinteraction) to pass the validation errors from the ViewModel to the View. I use this approach and call `TextInputLayout.SetError()` in the Android view to show the error message next to the input field.